# FetchXML attribute missing

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

When trying to retrieve an entity from `Dynamics CRM` using `FetchXML` one of the attributes appears to be missing.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="sb_eventbooking">
    <attribute name="sb_name" />
    <attribute name="sb_bookeridname" />    < problem here
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <atrribute ........
```

There are 18 attributes in the `FetchXML` file but when running the application only 17 are available:

[image]

And `sb_bookeridname` is missing.  If I go into the FetchXML file and enter an attribue that I know doesn't exist then I get an error:

```
'sb_eventbooking' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'fakeattribute'.
```

So the application accepts there *is* an attribue called 'sb_bookeridname' but I cannot get a value from it.  I know there can be issues with columns with `null` values but other attributes don't seem to have this problem.  I do use this check on all attributes and get values for all the other attributes:

```
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("sb_bookeridname") && entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("sb_bookeridname") != null)
{
     booking.bookeridname = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("sb_bookeridname");
}
```

Edit 1:

[image]

Comment: Ryan, what is sb_bookeridname? Is it a label for sb_bookerid lookup field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a lookup field with schema name: *sb_bookerid*. When we create a lookup field, CRM automatically creates a column in the table to store the text value corresponding to lookup. So when we create a lookup field *sb_bookerid*, then CRM will automatically create a column in the *sb_eventbooking* entity by the name *sb_bookeridname*.

This is the reason you do not receive an error on executing FetchXML query because a column with the name exists but CRM restricts from showing its value. So if you want to retrieve the value in *sb_bookerid* field, please use following -

```
if(entity.Contains("sb_bookerid"))
{
bookeridname=((EntityReference)entity.Attributes["sb_bookerid"]).Name
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's obivous now you say it.  Yup, that's where I was going wrong - needed EntityReference.  Thanks!  I was confused by similar tables NOT having lookups in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is cleaner way:

```
bookeridname = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("sb_bookerid")?.Name;
```